# For $\varphi:< S > \times X\to X$ and home. $h:X\to X$, what is size $d(\varphi(s,x), \psi(s, x))$? $\psi$ generated by $h\circ \varphi_s$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions

Let $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ be a continuous action of finitely generated group $G=\langle S \rangle$ on compact metric space $X$. Also, assume that $h:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism with $d(h(x), x)<\delta$ for all $x\in X$.

Assume that $\psi:G\times X\to X$ is generated by $h\circ \varphi_s$ for all $s\in S$.

Q1. What can say about the size $d(\psi(s, x), \varphi(s, x))$ for all $x\in X$?

Q2. Is it true $\psi(s, x)= h\circ \varphi_s(x)$? If it is true, what can say about equality $\psi(s_0s_1, x)= \psi(s_0, \psi(s_1, x))$?

Note that  $\psi(s_0, \psi(s_1, x))= h\circ\varphi_{s_0}\circ h\circ\varphi_{s_1}(x))$

Comment: What does it mean for $\psi$ to be generated by the $h \circ \varphi_s$? Please clarify. Also, what is the role of $\delta$?

Comment: @Marktmeisteter We assume that $G=<S>$ is finitely generated group. Hence continuous action $\varphi:<S>\times X\to X$ is generated by $\varphi_s$ where $s\in S$. Also, assume that $h:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism. If continuous action $\psi:<S>\times X\to X$ is generated by $h\circ \varphi_s$, then what can say about $\psi_s$?

Comment: @Marktmeister Also, if distance between $h:X\to X$ with identity map $i_X:X\to X$ is less that $\delta$ i.e. $d(h(x), x)<\delta$ for all $x\in X$, what can say about distance between $\varphi_s$ and $\psi_s$?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what it means for a group action to be generated by something. I understand that giving (say) $\psi$ is equivalent to giving a group homomorphism $G \to S_X$. Do you mean that the image of it is generated by the $h \circ \varphi_s$? However then you only specify the image of the homomorphism, but not the homomorphism itself. Can you give a precise definition?

Comment: @Marktmeister Assume that $G=<a, b>$. For every $g\in G$, there are $n, m$ with $g=a^nb^m$. Hence if $\varphi$ is generated by $\varphi_a=F$ and $\varphi_b=H$, where $F, H:X\to X$ are home. Then $\varphi(g, x)= F^n\circ H^m(x)$, where $F^2=F\circ F$.